# How to make language routes for cakephp 3 plguin

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

```
Router::scope('/:language/employer/', ['plugin' => 'EmployerPanel'], function ($routes) {  
    $routes->prefix('employer',function ($routes) {
        $routes->connect(':language/:controller',['plugin'=>'EmployerPanel']);
    });
     $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
});
```

this must go with plugin in **EmployerPanel** Plugin, Pages Controller and action is home with language en.

```
http://localhost/mmjob/en/empoyer/pages/home
```

but it is in debug request

```
language   => en
controller => Employer
action     => pages
pass(array)
plugin(null)
_matchedRoute/:language/:controller/:action/*
_ext(null)
```

how can i do for `_matchedRoute = /:language/:plugin/:controller:/:action`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Router::plugin(
    'EmployerPanel',
    ['path' => '/employer-panel'],
    function ($routes) {
        $routes->connect('/:language/employer/', ['plugin' => 'EmployerPanel', 'controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'home']);
        $routes->fallbacks('InflectedRoute');
    }
);

Go to http://localhost/mmjob/employer-panel/en/employer
```

Comment: This is fine working for this http://localhost/mmjob/employer-panel/en/employer link only? @Jsonras

Comment: Does that not answer your question? Do you need the plugin name to passed in?

Comment: I want language route for this whole Employer- panel @Jsonras  thank

Comment: So in your EmployerPanel > PagesController > you have a function called home right. public function home($language = null, $employer = null). Put the two params in the home function, once it gets called, you will have access to the language code and the employer.